# Call jsp Webservice

Tags: web-services, jsp

I need to call a webservice on another at `http://www.domainname/isValidCardNumber.jsp` from my Magento (PHP checkout form to check if a bonusid is valid. The webservice takes one paramter called Cardnr which must be 11 or 12 digit.

Webservice will return response in XML format. The xml for success and failure cases is given below.

Success:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<Response>
    <Result>true</Result>
    <ResultDetails><![CDATA[]]></ResultDetails>
</Response
Failure:
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<Response>
    <Result>false</Result>
    <ResultDetails><![CDATA[not valid id]></ResultDetails>
</Response>
```

How do I call the webservice and read out the response to my Magento shop. Have been looking at both Ajax and javascript, what is the best solution. Code hints will be much much appreciated.

Comment: Who will make the call? An app in your server or the HTML page on the browser directly? I'm assuming the web service is at a domain that is not the same as the html page's domain, yes?

Comment: Yes, it is a different domain, I'm calling the service from html. The call is part of the checkout procedure in a Magento webshop.

Answer (score 0):

You will have 2 options here.

1. **Call from UI, using ajax :** If you are going to use this, parsing XML will be difficult, but you don't have to. Just find out the index of '' tag and read the text after that, as thats all you are interested in. Even better, fo a indexOf the response string for 'true'. if you get non-negative output, its true, else false.
2. **from the backend :** The parsing can be done in the same way as above, although you can also use a XML parser to do it for you. That would be easy to maintain.

Comment: Thanks, could you give me som hints how to call from ajax and parse the response.

Comment: Tried calling the webservice with:

Comment: $.get("http://www.clubmatas.dk/web/forward/api/isValidCardNumber.jsp", { CardNumber : "12424" },
  function(data){
    alert("Data Loaded: " + data);
  });

Comment: link to webservice: http://www.clubmatas.dk/web/forward/api/isValidCardNumber.jsp